# What is a Waterfall Word™?

Tags: word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Waterfall Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

[image: Waterfall Words]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Waterfall Words™,Not Waterfall Words™
ANTACID,MEDICINE
BEAMED,SMILED
COSMOS,UNIVERSE
CRAMPS,PAIN
MEANT,IMPLIED
MEANY,BULLY
PANEL,FRAME
RABID,SICK
RAMPANT,WILD
SCRAM,GET
TACOS,CHIPS
TAXES,FINES
VISCUS,VISCERA
WAVY,BUMPY
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Waterfall words run down the keyboard (using qwerty layout), so a letter from the top row is followed by one from the middle row, then one from the bottom row, looping as needed.

Comment: That was quick!

Comment: I blame having a baby sitting on one hand!

Comment: OP should repost this question, with the examples in Dvorak, and see how long it takes then.

Comment: @Cody It took about [19 hours](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/112957/9000)