# What is a <ay.puann Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

*This puzzle is based off and inspired by the What is a Word™ series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) that have grown into [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22what+is+a%22+title%3A%22word%E2%84%A2%22+is%3Aquestion), [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22what+is+a%22+title%3A%22phrase%E2%84%A2%22+is%3Aquestion), and [Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22what+is+a%22+title%3A%22number%E2%84%A2%22+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.*

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a <ay.puann Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| <ay.puann Words™ | Not <ay.puann Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| AXLE | ROD |
| BLIMP | AIRSHIP |
| BLOB | SPIKE |
| BLOWLAMP | ACETYLENE |
| BRAWL | FIGHT |
| CAMP | BIVOUAC |
| COWLS | HOODS |
| COWPOX | VIRUS |
| COZY | WARM |
| FABLE | STORY |
| FOWLS | DUCKS |
| FOXY | CRAFTY |
| LUMPS | BUMPS |
| OKRA | PEAS |
| OWLS | HAWKS |
| POMPOM | CHEER |
| YOWLS | CRY |

In CSV format:

```
<ay.puann Words™,Not <ay.puann Words™
AXLE,ROD
BLIMP,AIRSHIP
BLOB,SPIKE
BLOWLAMP,ACETYLENE
BRAWL,FIGHT
CAMP,BIVOUAC
COWLS,HOODS
COWPOX,VIRUS
COZY,WARM
FABLE,STORY
FOWLS,DUCKS
FOXY,CRAFTY
LUMPS,BUMPS
OKRA,PEAS
OWLS,HAWKS
POMPOM,CHEER
YOWLS,CRY
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> "<ay.puann", when typed on a Dvorak keyboard with software that is set up to think it has a QWERTY keyboard attached, results in the word "waterfall".

To determine whether a word is an <ay.puann word or not,

> type it on a Dvorak keyboard. If the sequence of rows that you type on is top, middle, bottom (repeat) - starting anywhere in the sequence - then the word is an <ay.puann word.

Comment: [Correct](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44573/what-is-a-waterfall-word#comment133983_44574)

Comment: Hah, thanks for the cross-reference to the other question - I hadn't seen that, I generally don't enjoy the "X Word" puzzles but for some reason this one caught my eye. It took me about 15 mins from when I first saw it to when I posted the solution, based on my browser history timestamps (12:26 to 12:41).